# hidden true in extjs need to have same functionality as that of hide column

Tags: extjs

I have overridden the hide column functionality of extjs which is working fine. When the column is given hidden:true, during first time page load my hide functionality is not working. When i do hide/show column, it is working. Need to have the same functionality enabled during page load too

```
columnhide: function() {
    var cell = this.getEl().query('.x-grid-cell-inner');
    var collen = grid.columns.length;
    var i = 1;
    for (var y = i; y < cell.length; y = y + collen) {
        for (var x = 0; x < cell.length; x++) {
            if (x == y) {
                cell[x].style.display= "none"; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your text so it's readable.

Comment: For your code to display correctly, you need to indent it with 4 spaces (or use the buttons in the toolbar). I've edited your post to show you what it should give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the `columnhide` event fires only when a column is hidden **after** it has been rendered.

The simplest way to make your current code work would be to call `hide()` on the column, instead of using the `hidden` option.

Replacing `hidden: true` with the following in the column config will do the trick:

```
    ,listeners: {
        // we want to catch the event only the first time it is fired
        single: true
        ,afterrender: function() {
            this.hide();
        }
    }
```

This code will add a listener to the column you want to hide, and after the column is rendered, it will call its `hide()` method. That will trigger your event, etc.

Comment: Thank you.. But it is coming blank. Pls check here. http://jsfiddle.net/r7Tdy/16/

Comment: this.hide() Is hidding the whole grid not the column

Comment: I guess you've found out, but you must put the listener in the column config, not the grid's one.

Comment: Can you change my js fiddle code.. i tried it doesnt work... thanks for your help

Comment: In fact, the whole grid is not hidden, but it is crashed during its creation. There was a telling error in the console: 'Cannot read property 'columns' of undefined'. `renderTo` makes the grid render immediately, then your `afterrender` listener is called, then `this.hide()`, then your `columnhide` listener... All that before `Ext.create` returns, and so in your `columnhide` listener, `grid` is not yet defined. Tricky. One solution is to explicitly render the grid after its creation instead of using `renderTo`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/rixo/vsHNd/

Comment: thank you.. it works invoking column hide function but cell.length is coming zero inside that function

Comment: var cell = this.getEl().query('.x-grid-cell-inner');